# linux daemon can't run python file

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, daemon

I'm using a raspberry pi with Raspbian and I try to do this:

I made a file `myservice.sh`  in *etc/init.d*

```
...
DIR=/var/www/MDH/python
DAEMON=$DIR/myserv.py
DAEMON_NAME=myserv
DAEMON_USER=pi
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid
...
do_start () {
echo "Starting system do_start $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
echo "Started $DAEMON"
}
do_stop () {
...
ccase "$1" in

start|stop)
    do_${1}
    ;;

restart|reload|force-reload)
    do_stop
    do_start
    ;;

status)
    status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;

*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;

esac
exit 0
```

When i run `sudo service /etc/init.d/myservice.sh start` the prompt is ok:

```
Starting system do_start myserv daemon
. ok
Started /var/www/MDH/python/myserv.py
```

But if I do *sudo service /etc/init.d/myservice.sh status* my script is not running:

```
[FAIL] /var/www/MDH/python/myserv.py is not running ... failed!
```

If I try to run python script with `python /var/www/MDH/python/myserv.py` and it work OK.

Any idea to implement log or for debug better the script.

Comment: sorry my first question I wrong title "...can't RUN python file"

Comment: You can edit your original question to clarify it instead of using comments. Further, `service` just runs the according script, you can run `/etc/init.d/foo start` instead of `service foo start`, so that should allow you to further reduce the code required to reproduce the issue. That said, you didn't provide enough info by far, see the posting guidelines.

Comment: I recently started to use linux and I don't know much... is this the reason why I write for any idea to debug better the script and post more detailed information. thank you for the tip `service foo start`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt advice is good.  Also... How is `$PIDFILE` defined? Normally pid files are expected to be /var/run/*service*.pid  Check the definition and if/when it is OK, look in /var/run to see if the file is there and it contains the pid of your running service.

Comment: Yes, PIDFILE is defined I integrated in main post, and in `/var/run/myserv.pid` there is a number: 18895 and change ad every service start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved the script in python in the user folder:
\home\pi\

execution permission for my script
chmod +e myserv.py

also I add in myservice.sh:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: MDH daemon
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: daemon MDH 0.1
# Description: bla bla bla... MDH.
### END INIT INFO
```

now with 
service myservice.sh start

the python script work ok and the status,stop and restart are working good.
Why in folder /var/www/MDH/python/myserv.py not work???